# Why is rational exponentiation an algebraic operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exponentiation

I can't manage to understand what is the main criterion for an operation to be algebraic.
I orginally thought it was an operation that could be expressed via the  standard arithmetic operations (addition,subtraction,multiplication,division). However rational exponention fail to satisfy this property.
I looked into the wikipedia article but no insights on this specific are presented.

Comment: "Algebraic operation" is not a rigorously defined concept. And most of its rigorous versions do not allow $x^{2/3}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Since according to wipedia page it is a pretty well defined concept, I would accept an answer that claim it to not be that well defined. Just for people to have a second source to look for when wikipedia definitions  look a little bit nosense.

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti This seems worth mentioning on the Talk page for the Wikipedia article. Maybe with a link to here if a good answer is posted.

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti Would you consider "$\sqrt{x}$" to be an algebraic operation ?

Comment: My first guess of the definition of algebraic operation was one that sends algebraic numbers to algebraic numbers. This concept is not mentioned on the wikipedia page but I think this would make rational exponention an algebraic operation but irrational exponentiation would not be algebraic.

Comment: @Peter I honestly don't know....Probably I lack a deep understanding of what algebraic means, why should I or shouldn't I consider it to be?

Comment: @quarague I was trying to link it to the definition of algebric numbers, maybe this is the  right interpretation :)